# SNPRelate: how to give specific color to a population in PCA plot

Tags: pca

I am using SNPRelate for PCA analysis. Its using default color for different populations but I want to color them according to me. Plotting commands are like this:

> plot(tab$EV2, tab$EV1, col=as.integer(tab$pop),cex=1.2,pch=20,
>   + xlab="eigenvector 2", ylab="eigenvector 1")
>   legend("topleft", legend=levels(tab$pop), cex=1,pch=20, col=1:nlevels(tab$pop))

Head of the input file is like this:

sample.id   pop         EV1         EV2
1        A1 POP_I -0.10172849  0.03619405
2        A2 POP_I -0.15951814  0.08234857
3        A3 POP_I -0.15632495  0.08180843
4        A4 POP_I -0.09679447  0.07981108
5        A5 POP_I  0.11362360 -0.03186038
6        A6 POP_I  0.05594095 -0.05498351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Define a list of colors:**

> col.list <- c("gray", "blue", "green", "red", "blue", "yellow", ...)
>
> plot(tab$EV2, tab$EV1, col=col.list[as.integer(tab$pop)], cex=1.2, pch=20, xlab="eigenvector 2", ylab="eigenvector 1")
>
> legend("topleft", legend=levels(tab$pop), cex=1,pch=20, col=1:nlevels(tab$pop))